# Matlab if else loop

Tags: matlab

Welcome I want to check if number is even , non even or not integer and I don't know how to check last case. My code:

```
disp('check number');
x = input('give number = ');
if mod(x,2)== 0
    disp(' even number');
elseif mod(x,2)~= 0
    disp(' not even number');
else mod(x,2)== float
    disp('non integer');  
end
```

Comment: `if else` is not a loop.

Comment: can u help with this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `else` clause doesn't take a conditional expression, so in order to use it we need to make sure that all integers are handled before we get there. Fortunately, if we catch all *even* integers and all *odd* integers, anything left is not an integer.

The `if` clause looks good, if `mod(x,2) == 0`, then it's even, so let's keep that. For the `elseif` part, for all integers, `mod(x,1) == 1`. Normally this would catch both odd and even integers, but since we've already handled all of the even integers in the `if` clause, we can safely assume that any integers that get here are odd. Anything that makes it past these two conditions must be a non-integer.

```
disp('check number');
x = input('give number = ');
if mod(x,2) == 0
    disp(' even number');
elseif mod(x,1) == 0
    disp(' not even number');
else
    disp('non integer');
end
```